Any case that the return type of a Web API has to be an Observable and can NOT be a Single?
I'm learning RxJava and Retrofit2 and wondering if there is any case that the return type of a Web API has to be an Observable and can not be a Single.
As far as I can think of   ... even paged datas are combined by some Single calls... So the Web API still returns Single and we can then combine them to an Observable.
Am I missing something? Thanks.
